# Java Exception is not thrown

Tags: java, exception, ejb

I wrote a user registration service which should throw an Exception if the user already exists. Here is the code for the register method:

```
    public User register(User user, String role) throws UserExistsException{
    boolean userExists = existUserInDB(user);
    if(userExists) {
        logger.info("Yes, this user exists!");
        throw new UserExistsException("This user already exists in database!");
    }

    try {

        String encryptedPassword = getEncryptedPassword(user.getPassword(), getSalt(user));
        user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

        Role userRole;

        if (role == null){
            TypedQuery<Role> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT r "+
                    "FROM Role r "+
                    "WHERE rolename = 'User'", Role.class);
            userRole = query.getSingleResult();
        } else {
            TypedQuery<Role> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT r "+
                    "FROM Role r "+
                    "WHERE rolename = '"+role+"'", Role.class);
            userRole = query.getSingleResult();
        }

        user.getRoles().add(userRole);
        userRole.getUsers().add(user);

        entityManager.persist(userRole);
        entityManager.persist(user);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {

        logger.warning("CryptAPI faild: " + e.getMessage());

    }

    return user;
}
```

The logging confirms, that the *existUserInDB* method returns the correct boolean value. The given user exists in the database. But the exception is never thrown.
I have a lot of self implemented Exceptions in my application which all are thrown and catched correctly. All but this one. Can somebody help me with this?

And here is the code where I call the register method.

```
    public String register() {
    regUser.setEmail(this.emailAdd);

    try {

        userService.register(regUser, userRole);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Der Benutzer wurde erfolgreich registriert.", null));
        context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);


    } catch (UserExistsException e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Der Benutzer ist bereits registriert!", null));
    }
    curSession.setCurrentUser(regUser);
    init();
    return "home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

And here is the class definition of the exception:

```
public class UserExistsException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9218609941894034576L;

public UserExistsException(){
    super();
}

public UserExistsException(String message){
    super(message);
}

}
```

Comment: Which exception should be thrown where? And if all is correct why should it be thrown?

Comment: is this line printed? `logger.info("Yes, this user exists!");`

Comment: And, show the code where you are expecting this exception. i.e. from where `register` is called ?

Comment: Are you talking about `throw new UserExistsException("This user already exists in database!");`? Did you debug your code to see whether that line is executed?

Comment: Yes, this line is printed. @Thomas: the exception in the first if statement should be thrown because I registered a user which already exists in the database. So it's an expected Exception case

Comment: Please show the code where you called this method

Comment: Ok so the rest of the code you posted is irrelevant but the relevant parts (where you call the method and want to handle the exception) are missing. Please fix that otherwise it's hard to help. And if the print statement right before the throw statement is executed the exception should be thrown. It might just be cought somewhere (which we can't tell due to the missing parts).

Comment: As you said @Thomas, "if the print statement right berofe the thrown statement is executed the exceptoin should be thrown." That exactly is my problem. I've added the call of the register method

Comment: So do you see the message `Der Benutzer wurde erfolgreich registriert.`? That would indicate the exception is not thrown. As I said, stepping through the code with a debugger should help here. It also might provide hints for the code that is running not matching the sources, e.g. when the debugger steps into seemingly empty lines etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of all above I was able to solve it. The problem was not the thrown exception. Sorry for the incorrect title. The problem was the redirect I had in the return statement of the calling method. So my FacesMessage got lost. I fixed it with the following lines in the catch clause:

```
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Der Benutzer existiert bereits.", null));
        context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

Thank you to all persons above for guiding me to the right path.

Answer (score 1):

The problem maybe int the line below that will not do the right things which you want.

```
    catch (UserExistsException e) {
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Der Benutzer ist bereits registriert!", null));
    }
```

You can check that code executed here like this:

```
catch (UserExistsException e) {
     System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Der Benutzer ist bereits registriert!", null));
        }
```

If the line printed, then it means the Exception has been thrown. But the rest of code did not do the things that you want from.

Comment: Thank you very much. The line is printed, so the exception, as you said, is thrown. I can also confirm this now in the debugger. My only problem seems to be the rendering of the error message.